# Version of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

Is there any version of SQL Server 2008 Express which could be run on all computers (32bit & 64 bit)?

I have a version of SQL Server 2005 Express X86, it works very well on both platforms but when I tried SQL Server 2008 Express X86, and ran it on 64bit system, it failed.

Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2009/10/20/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-32bit-on-windows-2008-x64.aspx

Comment: What about to download the correct version from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Google or [Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download) search will send you to these pages:

- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695
- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express Edition  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438
- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062
- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Express http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

On `Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express` download page, under `Supported Operating System`:

> Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack 3
>
> - 32-Bit Systems: Computer with Intel or compatible 1GHz or faster processor (2 GHz or faster is recommended. Only a single processor is supported)
> - 64-Bit Systems: 1.4 GHz or higher processor (2 GHz or faster is recommended. Only a single processor is supported)